# Regex Expression Issue

Tags: php, regex

I have the below regex expression and I'm trying to break it into two parts, there might not always be the the two parts though.

> Section Level: Very Low.  Type: Animal.

I'm using the below to break it by characters but I need to be able to break by the string, identify the level and type so they can be returned into two separate database columns. For example I need to check the string and see if there is anything matching 'Section Level: {text}.' and insert it into the level column in the database and the same for type, I need to check the string for 'Type: {text}.' and insert it into a type column.

```
(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\.)
```

I've been able to get the first piece out using `(\w*)(.*?)(?=\.)` but still can't for the life of me get the second part.

Comment: and what does not work?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Comment: Like I said in the post, I need to break it up based on the text between 'Level:' and the next full stop and then also break it up on 'Type:' and the next full stop after type but there wont always be a type or a level.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, how did you even get that from my post, I clearly explained what I'm trying to do and what I've already tried to solve my issue. I'm just asking to be pointed in the right direction, I never said I want you to write the code!

Comment: Sorry, i misinterpreted your perpose because your regular expression is perfectly fits for your string example, so i actually don't see how we could help you, exept writing the code in php. Cold you please provide test cases, where you regex is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following regex should work for you:

```
(?=\w)(?:Section\s+Level:\s*([^.]+)\.)?\s*(?:Type:\s*([^.]+)\.)?
```

With both `Level` and `Type` fields as optional fields.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/GpSHs69YHy

Comment: Thanks for that, Slight change to it, I forgot to add in the other piece of text, once I do this it seems to return 3 array elements, I've changed the regex at this link, http://www.rubular.com/r/9oODd88KIg

Comment: You should really consider not using a regex for this as you will always have expand it for every new word. Also this regex, due to making nearly everything optional, will match anything containing at least a dot, like "......", ".aaaaaaaa", etc. The strtok alternative seems more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @migg Pls pay close attention to the regex before claiming `will match anything containing at least a dot`

Comment: @atallon: Your suggested regex at http://www.rubular.com/r/9oODd88KIg looks good to me.

Comment: Ok... maybe I should clarify that it generates "a lot of empty matching groups" for anything containing at least a dot ;)

Comment: @migg: Please provide some examples of `a lot of empty matching groups`. Also remember both fields are optional as per OP.

Comment: Sorry... tested it with PHP and seems like only this rubular tool is broken and shows a lot of empty matching groups. I also misread the dot as a literal dot... so my fault. Regex works, but still is not my favorite solution for this, as strtok does scale better.

Comment: Ok, tried this also, curious as to why it works on the rubular site but it doesn't work properly at this example: http://regexr.com?34avp

Comment: Thanks for that example, see this example here, if the string only has one match it ignores any matches, http://ideone.com/EqoRSV

Comment: @atallon: I see that but you didn't make it clear if starting text `"Section "` is also optional. Pls tell me if `"Section "` is also optional and I can make minor adjustment to regex.

Comment: Glad that it worked out. Check this link for more examples: http://ideone.com/X61NpN

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) rather than regular expressions:

```
$string = 'Level: Very Low. Type: Animal.';

$parts = array();

for ($s = strtok($string, '.'); $s; $s = strtok('.'))
{

  $array = explode(':', $s);

  $parts[trim($array[0])] = trim($array[1]);

}

print_r($parts);
```

That would give you:

```
Array
(
    [Level] => Very Low
    [Type] => Animal
)
```

The benefit is that if you ever added something else, say `Gender: Male` then you wouldn't have to modify the code (much).